# How JVM know the location a variable in stack of a method?

Tags: java, stack-memory

This question may be a silly one or may be a duplicate. I am confused with how the variables are retrieved from stack when program is referring to that variable. 
An object is stored in  heap and the location is stored in the reference variable and the reference variable containing the heap address itself is stored in stack. But how JVM figure out that reference variable is stored in what location in stack.

Lets consider the example just to make clear what I am confused about.

```
Class Test {
    public void test() {
        Object a = new Bar();
        Object b = new Foo();
        System.out.println(a);
    }
}
```

Lets say method test() is getting executed. So stack will be allocated for test().

Now when the line '**Object a = new Bar();**' is executed , Bar object will be created in Heap and the actual variable **'a'**, whose value is the address location of the Bar object , will be stored in stack of test().

Again on the line '**Object b = new Foo();**' same thing happens. Foo object will be created in Heap and the actual variable **'b'** ,whose value is the address location of the Foo object,  will be stored in stack of test().

Now when he line '**System.out.println(a);**' is executed , how does JVM know from which location in the stack , the value of **'a'** should be retrieved. Means what links the variable 'a' and its location in the stack ?

Answer (score 11):

You're almost there, there's just one missing link in your understanding.

Local variables (or the references to the object stored in a local variable, if we're talking about non-primitive types) are actually stored in a **local variable table**, not on the operand stack. They're only pushed onto the stack when they are to be used by a call.

*(What is confusing is that the local variable table itself is also stored on a stack, but that's a separate stack from what the bytecode uses for operands. From the bytecode's perspective it is a real table, with fixed size and freely indexable.)*

You can use `javap` to look at what bytecode is generated from your code. What you'll see is something like this:

```
public void test();
descriptor: ()V
flags: ACC_PUBLIC
Code:
  stack=3, locals=3, args_size=1
    0: new           #2                  // class Test$Bar
    3: dup
    4: invokespecial #3                  // Method Test$Bar."<init>":()V
    7: astore_1
    8: new           #4                  // class Test$Foo
   11: dup
   12: invokespecial #5                  // Method Test$Foo."<init>":()V
   15: astore_2
   16: getstatic     #6                  // Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
   19: aload_1
   20: invokevirtual #7                  // Method java/io/PrintStream.println:(Ljava/lang/Object;)V
   23: return
}
```

First of all, what is this line?

```
  stack=3, locals=3, args_size=1
```

It is metadata that tells the JVM that this method has an operand stack no deeper than 3 entries, 3 local variables and takes 1 argument. But surely that isn't right, our method takes no argument and clearly only has 2 local variables!

The answer to this is that non-static methods always have a "0th argument": `this`. This explains the argument count, and leads us to the next important discovery: **arguments of a method are stored in the local variable table too**. So our table will have entries 0,1,2, with 0 containing `this` at the start and 1 and 2 uninitialised.

With that out of the way, let's look at the code! First up it's lines `0-7`:

1. The `new` opcode creates a new instance of `Bar` and stores the reference on the stack.
2. `dup` creates a copy of the same reference on the top of the stack (so you've got two copies now sitting there)
3. `invokespecial #3` calls the constructor of `Bar` and consumes the top of the stack. (now we've only got one copy left)
4. `astore_1` stores the remaining reference in local variable number number `1` (`0` is for `this` in this case)

This is what `Object a = new Bar();` has been compiled into. Then you get the same for `Object b = new Foo();` (lines `8-15`).

And then comes the interesting bit, from line `16`:

1. `getstatic #6` pushes the value of `System.out` on the stack
2. `aload_1` pushes local variable number 1 (`a`) on the stack too
3. `invokevirtual #7` consumes both entries, calling `println()` on `System.out` with `a` as its input parameter.

**If you want to delve into it deeper, or you just want to point out my mistakes, the official reference for all of the above is [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-2.html#jvms-2.6.1).**

Comment: Thanks for the detailed reply. Just clarifying :  astore_x will push to position 'x'  in the local variable table and aload_x will push the item stored at position 'x' in the table to the stack. That is the generic idea rt ?

Comment: @Dinkan Exactly, and of course `astore_x`  pops the value off the stack too.

Comment: Okay . Got it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

THe JVM stores Stack Frames and these hold arrays for the variables.

```
Each frame (§2.6) contains an array of variables known as its local variables.
[...]
Local variables are addressed by indexing.
```

Found [Here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-2.html#jvms-2.6.1)

Answer (score 0):

JVM is not a onefold data structure, actually it has several different mechanisms. When a program is executed, JVM organizes all memories it needs and allocate them into several different memory stacks called *runtime data areas*.

Here is a more detailed explanation: [Architecture of JVM](https://www.artima.com/insidejvm/ed2/jvmP.html)